# Meaining of "holler"?

Tags: lyrics

In the context of it's use in the song "Copperhead Road".

http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/steveearle/copperheadroad.html

Examples:

- "He headed up the holler with everything he had"
- "I plant it up the holler down Copperhead Road"

Answer (score 5):

**Holler** is a regionalism (mainly in Kentucky and West Virginia in the US) meaing a **hollow**, a low valley between two hills. The [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=holler) (maybe not the best reference) has this definition:

> in the south east mountains of the united states this word is used
>   instead of hollow;A small rising valley region between two hills or
>   mountains;often containing a creek

Comment: While it's unlikely to cause confusion, John Ringo's _Live Free or Die_ intentionally misuses the term by applying it to New Hampshire, where the term is never used. Since he also talks about moonshiners using the hollers, it's clear that he's having a bit of fun.